# Text with background color and rounded borders in asciidoctor-pdf

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I am trying to create some badge-like texts for my documentation, to highlight the status of some issues.

Here are some examples (jira issues embedded in a confluence wiki)

[Example for a "closed"-badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGu4y.png)

[Example for "waiting for solution"-badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgTC1.png)

I even struggle to find any simple way to set a background-color for a text in asciidoctor-pdf.

The most promising attempt was using a themed button-macro.

`btn:[Closed]`

with this theme-section:

```
button:
  background-color: #88FF88
  border-color: #33FF33
  border-radius: 5
  border-width: 0.5
  border-offset: 3.0
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUEnE.png) is quite close to what I hoped to achieve, however I cannot have buttons with different colors. Or is it possible to overwrite the theme-values in the *.adoc file itself?

Is there any other possibility to create something similar in asciidoc-pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to achive this with roles.

I have at the top of my `.adoc` file:

```
:pdf-theme: my-theme.yml
```

Then I have a file called `my-theme.yml` in the same directory as my `.adoc`:

```
extends: default

role:
  done:
    font-color: ffffff
    background-color: #88FF88
    border-color: #33FF33
    border-radius: 2
    border-width: 0.5
    border-offset: .0
```

When I use it, I do this:

```
[.done]#DONE#
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, was already using roles but did not know that I can also define borders in them. I am using this configuration now:
green:
    font-color: #006644
    font_size: 7
    font_style: bold
    background-color: #e3fcef
    border-color: #e3fcef
    border-radius: 3
    border-width: 0.5
    border-offset: 1.0